# std::abs(std::complex) too slow

Tags: c++, std, complex-numbers

Why running `std::abs` over a big complex array is about 8 times slower than using `sqrt` and `norm`?

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef complex<double> compd;

    vector<compd> arr(2e7);
    for (compd& c : arr)
    {
        c.real(rand());
        c.imag(rand());
    }

    double sm = 0;
    clock_t tm = clock();
    for (const compd& c : arr)
    {
        sm += abs(c);
    }
    cout << sm << ' ' << clock() - tm << endl; // 5.01554e+011 - 1640 ms

    sm = 0;
    tm = clock();
    for (const compd& c : arr)
    {
        sm += sqrt(norm(c));
    }
    cout << sm << ' ' << clock() - tm << endl; // 5.01554e+011 - 154

    sm = 0;
    tm = clock();
    for (const compd& c : arr)
    {
        sm += hypot(c.real(), c.imag());
    }
    cout << sm << ' ' << clock() - tm << endl; // 5.01554e+011 - 221
}
```

Comment: In any question about performance, please include details of how you generated the inputs, how many experiments you performed, how you performed the timing, the times for each experiment etc.

Comment: Try `-ffast-math`?

Comment: Sample code added.
I tested with some other compilers and got different results.

Comment: Your time measurement has a bug, instead of printing `tm`, you should print `clock()-tm`. And it would be sensible to add your measurement results to the question as well.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code and added results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the two are not to be taken as identical in the strict sense.

From [cppreference on `std::abs(std::complex)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/abs):

> Errors and special cases are handled as if the function is implemented as `std::hypot(std::real(z), std::imag(z))`

Also from [cppreference on `std::norm(std::complex)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/norm):

> The norm calculated by this function is also known as field norm or absolute square.
>
> The Euclidean norm of a complex number is provided by `std::abs`, which is more costly to compute. In some situations, it may be replaced by `std::norm`, for example, if `abs(z1) > abs(z2)` then `norm(z1) > norm(z2)`.

In short, there are cases where a different result is obtained from each function. Some of these may be found in [`std::hypot`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot). There the notes also mention the following:

> `std::hypot(x, y)` is equivalent to `std::abs(std::complex<double>(x,y))`

In general the accuracy of the result may be different (due to the usual floating point mess), and it seems the functions were designed in such a way to be as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 5):

The main reason is that `abs` handles underflow and overflow during intermediate computations.

So, if `norm` under/overflows, your formula returns an incorrect/inaccurate result, while `abs` will return the correct one (so, for example, if your input numbers are in the range of 10<sup>200</sup>, then the result should be around 10<sup>200</sup> as well. But your formula will give you `inf`, or a floating point exception, because the intermediate `norm` is around 10<sup>400</sup>, which is out of range. Note, I've supposed IEEE-754 64-bit floating point here).

Another reason is that `abs` may give a little bit more precise result.

If you don't need to handle these cases, because your input numbers are "well-behaved" (and don't need the possible more precise result), feel free to use your formula.